# Expression in RDLC textbox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rdlc, reportviewer

Is it possible to write a `query` as an `expression` in a textbox in rdlc? I am trying to show `row position` of a field after ordering them in descending order.

If not possible, how can I achieve this apart from passing the values via parameters?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just do this in the SQL you use to pull the data for the report?

Comment: you mean via dataset?

Comment: Well you're using the term 'rows' so I take that to mean you are populating the report from a database, and yes, using a dataset. Therefore I'd expect that you can use an ORDER BY clause and a ROW_NUMBER in the SQL query that populates the dataset.

Comment: There's also Common Functions, Miscellaneous, RowNumber in the RDLC designer - should've mentioned that first, thought it was there somehwere but couldn't find it myself!

Comment: thinking of using custom codes

Comment: this does not solve your problem? `=RowNumber()`

Comment: @Ppp I have to ORDER the rows and use a WHERE clause also

Comment: I mean using the `=RowNumber()` expression in the table of the report? sorry if i understand your question wrongly.

Comment: I was looking for a way to `Rank` data gotten from dataset after ordering in `Descending Order`. I was able to achieve this by ranking all data then passing them through `parameters` to the ReportViewer.